# How can I pass a <router-link> in a string in an object as a prop to a child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

Based on what parent component calls the child component (a modal) the text of the modal is be populated with an object passed in as a prop from the parent component.

In one instance, one of the items of the object (`modalText`) I'm passing in contains a router-link. The element shows up in the console and the text shows up in the browser, but the linking doesn't work.

**Parent**

```
modalText: {
  subHeadline: `You can find ${this.name} in the <router-link :to="{name:'PartArea'}">part area</router-link> of your list`,
}
```

**Child (modal)**

```
<h2 v-html="modalText.subHeadline">{{modalText.subHeadline}}</h2>
```

Comment: No. A workable approach would be exposing a slot in your child component. Otherwise you will have to compile that subHeadline somehow.

Comment: Figured it out - I'm using i18n for translations, so I used their path and action methods to insert my router link into the middle of this text

Comment: Glad to hear it!